# Dividing an ODE by $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When solving ODEs in class, the lecturer frequently divides the equations by $x$, usually in order to get it to its normalized form.

But $x$ might be zero sometimes,

How do we handle this operation, and what are its implications?

Example:

$x\cdot y' = y$

Divided by x: $y' = \frac{y}{x}$

Thank you.

Comment: can you send us an example please?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Example was added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: I believe you have to consider something called (Ordinary, regular, irregular) singular points. EDIT: NVM those are for second order

Comment: In the example provided, if $x=0$ then the solution ceases to be unique (since $y = x$ and $y = 0$ are both solutions).

Comment: @DemetriP I'll show you what I don't understand: in the aforementioned equation, y = k*x is a solution (k - const), that is defined for x=0, and complies with the ODE. But when I have divided the equation, I have completely ignored the fact that x might be zero, and still received a valid solution that is defined for x=0.

But what are the "cases" which dividing by x will have a side-effect?

Comment: @DemetriP Ok, in this example existence and uniqueness theorem isn't valid for x=0, but I guess that we can think of examples for which dividing by x doesn't affect fulfilling the conditions for existence and uniqueness at x=0.

Comment: I highly suspect that the reason your professor glossed over the detail has something to do with uniqueness.  What exactly, I can't say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45712/discussion-between-taru-and-demetri-p).

Comment: I wanted to ask the same question, but about a second order ODE, namely Bessel equation. Explanations given here just don't fit, especially in the case where we define initial conditions for $x=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a comment too long to be put in the comments section.

It is strange that so many people wary about dividing by a variable equal to $0$ , in the process of solving ODEs.

Why not to state at the first beginning : "The solving will be carried out outside the range where the term comes to $0$". The case $0$ will be considered latter.

For example : $\quad xy'=y\quad$

We divide by $x$ and by $y$ in the range of solutions where $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$.

This leads to $\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x}$ .

Integration leads to $\quad y=c\:x\quad$, of course in case of  $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ .

Then, we observe that $y=0$ is also solution of the ODE any $x$, corresponding to the case $c=0$. We also observe that in $y=xy'$ , $x=0$ implies $y=0$ which is consistent with $y=c\:x$.

So, the solution $y=c\:x$ which is valid for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ can be extended to the cases $x=0$ and/or $y=0$.

Comment: One reason people are wary is that there is often a little more work to be done. There may be solutions that are sometimes zero, without being identically zero. A good example to consider is $y' = \sqrt{y}$.If you just copy the above reasoning, you will miss lots of solutions.

Comment: @mrf : Yes, I know. But following the above reasoning one find that the solutions of $y'=\sqrt{y}$ are $y=\left(\frac{x+c}{2}\right)^2$ and $y=0$ any $x$, including the solution $(0,0)$. What are the missing solutions ?

Comment: The solutions you're missing are patched versions of the two, for example: $$y = \begin{cases} 0 & x < -c \\ (x+c)^2/2 & x \ge -c \end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes, I agree. When I wrote "the solutions are $y=\left(\frac{x+c}{2}\right)^2$ AND $y=0$ " this includes what you call "patched versions" : I didn't knew this expression. Instead of, may be I should write "and" and "together" ?. A question of vocabulary. I suspect that we agree but with different viewpoints. Of course, my comment above doesn't miss the cases of non unique solutions.

Comment: What about the case when the initial condition(s) is defined for $x=0$? When we have to include $x=0$ from the start... for example, Bessel equation of zero order $$x^2 y_{xx}+xy_x-x^2y=0$$ with initial conditions $y(0)=1$ and $y_x(0)=0$?

Comment: If you want to give an example in order to help the OP, write down the example. Don't ask a question, I am not the OP. My comment was to help him, nothing more.